# Can't understand the usage of strchr to get the position of a charcter in a string in C

Tags: c, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic, string.h, strchr

This code will output the index of a charcter in a string :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

   char str[100]="birds are dying";
   char *p;

   p = strchr(str,'e'); 
   int i=p-str;

   printf("%d" , i);

   return 0;
}
```

the only line of code that i can't understand is :

```
int i=p-str;
```

1. str is a string and p also , i searched about the result of printing a string as an integer and found that it is an undefined behaviour , so what does it actually return ?
2. p - str is : `e dying - birds are dying` , when somehow we change it to an integer why does it return a positive value

Thanks

Comment: "string" is a loaded term in C: can mean different things on different contexts. In your code `str` is an array of 16 characters (in many contexts [such as basic arithmetic] using its identifier converts that to a pointer to its first element), `p` is a pointer to char. Subtracting two pointers (which point somewhere inside the sme object) yields  the distance in number of elements of the underlying type (distance in chars in your case).

Comment: You can see the type of the expression is `int`. So why do you think you are "printing a string as an integer"? You're printing an `int` as an integer.

Comment: Search term: *pointer arithmetic*

Comment: Just to be more specific: your "string - string" is in fact "pointer - array" which gets converted to "pointer - pointer". The result of that subtraction has type `ptrdiff_t`, and is converted to `int` by the assignment

Comment: @pmg Braino/typo: `ptr_diff` => `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific example, always check that the returned pointer isn't NULL, in case strchr didn't find the character. `NULL - str` would invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a  string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined

In this call

```
p = strchr(str,'e');
```

the function `strchr` returns a pointer that points to the symbol `'e'.`

In the expression

```
p-str
```

The object str having the array type `char[100]`  is implicitly convereted to pointer to its first element. So the expression represents a difference of two pointers.

And according to the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
> the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
> object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
> array elements....

Thus the difference is the number of elements between two pointers that yields the index of the found symbol because the expression `str` (after implicit conversion of the array `str` to pointer) points to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a string - it is a pointer.  This is pointer arithmetic which is legal.  It works in units of the pointees.  Supposing you had

```
double x[10], *start, *end;
integer exclusive;

start = &x[2];
end = &x[4];
exclusive = end - start;
printf("%d\n", exclusive);
```

What do you think will be printed?  You will get 2: not 2 * sizeof(double).

Comment: For OP's original `p-str`, it is also worth mentioning that `str` is converted from array to pointer, equivalent to `p-&str[0]`.

Comment: but why does that happen or how , is it because the 2 pointers return their memory location for example 10012 - 10010

Comment: "because the 2 pointers return their memory location for example 10012 - 10010" yes, that is a simplified way to look at it

Comment: thanks pmg for being helpful u can post this as an answer

Comment: also is it best way to find position of a charcter in a string?